# How to find the keyboard button(s) a program is waiting for?

Tags: keyboard, executable, shortcut

I have an old program without a user manual, and where at some point, I need to enter a specific command on the keyboard (ex: ‘Crtl+F’). Unfortunately, the guy who made this program is a Chinese guy, who left our group many years ago, and he didn’t let us the source code. We would like to use this program but one option needs this keyboard trick to work, and since he used a Chinese keyboard, I didn’t succeed to figure out what could be this shortcut. Is there any way to find it from the executable file?

Comment: Try this http://imgur.com/u3lWw

Comment: Argh ... I tried :) With every letter, symbol, Ctrl, Atl, ... I still have the picture of this option window in mind, but no way to find how to get it again.